# Re-sizing controls that are next to each other when maximizing window size

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012, maximize-window

I am having trouble re-sizing some of my controls when I give a window the ability to be maximized. The two controls lies next to each in the window as displayed in the picture. I have experimented with various ways of anchoring, docking, and auto growing them, but it always seems to move or grow them in some odd way.
[image]

What I want is when the window is maximized, the 2 controls should each grow and fill half the width of the window, leaving the other half to the other control as in the picture below. 
[image]
Am I missing something in Visual Studio designer mode, or should this be done some way in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with your form's Resize event:

**EDIT:** Anchor your groupboxes' top & bottom only.

> ```
>     private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         groupBox1.Left = 5;
>         groupBox2.Left = groupBox1.Left + groupBox1.Width + 5;
>         groupBox1.Width = groupBox2.Width = this.Width / 2;  
>     }
> ```